# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''../configs/variables.php\');' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in ... on line 275

Tags: php

Tengo el error que dice el título en PHP, afecta donde sale el primer include (variables.php) del código: (esa es la línea 275)

```
echo "INFO: Defining shortened URL content.<br>";
if(!isset($_GET['mcpe']))
{
echo "WARNING: mcpe parameter specified.";
$urlcontent = '<?php
$servername = "'.$servername.'";
$longlink = "'.$longlink.'";
$alias = "'.$alias.'";
$password = "'.$password.'";
include (\'../configs/variables.php\');
include (\'../configs/template.php\');
?>';

}
else {
unset($urlcontent);
// No template, instant redirect
$urlcontent = '<?php
$servername = "'.$servername.'";
$longlink = "'.$longlink.'";
$alias = "'.$alias.'";
$password = "'.$password.'";
include (\'../configs/variables.php\');
include (\'../configs/template.php\');
header("Refresh:0; url='.$longlink.'")';
?>';
echo "WARNING: mcpe parameter not specified.";

}
```

Gracias

Comment: Eliminar los `backslashes \ `  , en los  `include` `('../configs/variables.php');`

Comment: @Dev.Joel Los uso porque me dijieron que si no los pongo me va a regresar un error

Comment: No es así , el `backslash`  para escapar caracteres. la función `include` recibe un cadena. elimina dichos \ y se solucionará tu error.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Lo hice y da el error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '';' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ... on line 289, fijate que $urlcontent está con comillas y no comillas dobles, me lo dijieron y me funciono pero ahora no sé que pasa que ya no funciona

Comment: Está mal concatenada tu cadena.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Puedes ser un poco más completo.. ? necesito una solución pronta ya que estoy "partnering" con alguien y necesito esto

Comment: Lo que es un milagro es que el intérprete php analice algo. Las etiquetas <?php y ?> se usan para indicar dónde comenzar a analizar código php... pero parece que intentas que $content contenga código php sin interpretar... ¿Lo estás haciendo a drede?

Comment: @RicardoFernandez Esto es un acortador de urls, $urlcontent define el código php de cada archivo. No uso bases de datos  y ese es el objetivo d este acortador. No entiendo tu comentario?

Comment: Pues que estás intentando que una variable tenga este contenido literalmente y sin interpretar: '<?php $servername = "'.$servername.'"; $longlink = "'.$longlink.'"; $alias = "'.$alias.'"; $password = "'.$password.'"; include (\'../configs/variables.php\');include (\'../configs/template.php\');header("Refresh:0; url='.$longlink.'")';?>' y es sencillamente incomprensible. Al menos para mí.

Comment: Sería interesante saber **dónde usarás `$urlcontent`, si dentro de PHP, en un HTML... o dónde**, pues como dice @RicardoFernandez es extraño que quieras almacenar en una variable todo un script PHP `<?php ...  ?>`. ¿Estás **obligado** a hacerlo así por algún motivo, o sea, estás obligado a guardar un script entero en una variable porque luego lo vas a usar en otro entorno que no es el servidor? Incluso me pregunto si eso funcionará, tu script en una variable que además tiene variables dentro de variables, es decir, con el mismo nombre (`$servername=$servername...`) No sé, es algo extraño.

Answer (score 1):

- No usar `backslashes \` antes de una cadena . estás se usan para escapar caracteres . En su caso para el `include` no es necesario.

  ```
  include ('../configs/variables.php');
  include ('../configs/template.php');
  ```
- Estas concatenando Mal la variable `urlcontent`  en el `Else`

  ```
   $urlcontent = '<?php
   $servername = "'.$servername.'";
   $longlink = "'.$longlink.'";
   $alias = "'.$alias.'";
   $password = "'.$password.'";
   include ("../configs/variables.php");
   include ("../configs/template.php");
   header("Refresh:0; url="'.$longlink.'");
  ?>';
  ```